# Access view controller from referencing storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

As I know that referencing storyboard can be used to make the multiple storyboard with the same storyboard reference. If all View Controllers hierarchy is connected via the segue it works.

I want to know how to use referencing storyboard without segue between View controllers, because one view controller may be used in multiple ways or may need to access the view controller with the storyboard identifier from the new referencing storyboard.

Please let me know, I want to use referencing storyboard's view controller without the segue.

Comment: use storyboard id

Comment: I tried. but it crashes.

Comment: Because that particular view controller not found in the main.storyboard.

Comment: can you pls update your question with crash report

Comment: I am having this crash "doesn't contain a view controller 
with identifier 'SpecificVC'", when I want to access the view controller directly from the referencing storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You could do somthing like this...

```
@IBAction func tapButtonToShowOtherController(_ sender: Any?) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    //storyboard identifier set in storyboard "userSB"
    let aVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "userSB") as? AViewController          
    aVC?.udelegate = self
    self.present(aVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It will crash the app.

Comment: whats the terminal telling you...why has It crashed?

Answer (score 0):

Give the id to storyboard in identity inspecter like "ViewController_id"

```
MyCartViewController* destVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyCartViewController_id"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: It will crash the app.

Comment: what is issue in this code. can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    MyNewViewController *myVC = (MyNewViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewCont"];
```

Comment: Thanks @Jagveer, but I want to access all the view controller from the Main.storyboard, and I am having multiple referencing storyboard not multiple storyboards.

Comment: but you will call one view controller at a time

Answer (score 0):

Select your viewcontroller from storyboard and select **identity inspecter** give stoary board id whatever you want

[image]

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your storyboard name" bundle:nil];
    MyNewViewController *myVC = (MyNewViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your storyboard id"];
```

I downloaded sample at here https://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards

They have used storyboard reference as segue.Here i have modified something below:

1.select Checklists.stoaryboard

2.Remove ChecklistDetailViewController segue.

3.Select ChecklistsViewController.swift

4.Add following code:**Its working without segue**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ChecklistDetail", bundle: nil)
        let aVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChecklistDetailViewController") as? ChecklistDetailViewController
        aVC?.checklist = checklists[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(aVC!, animated: true)


    }
```

5.comment **prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)** method.

Here i have understand:

When you are using, storyboard reference You need to mention **ReferenceID**

[image]

Then you can take **viewcontroller** by giving **stoarboard name** with Respective **storyboardId**

Comment: #karthikeyan it works in the case of single storyboard, I am having multiple referencing storyboard, and access the vc with the main storyboard.

Comment: what do you mean multiple referencing storyboard?

Comment: I mean to say I am having a Main.storyboard and other 2 storyboard which is being referencing from the Main.storyboard. Please read in detail about the same here https://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards

Comment: Thanks, #karthikeyan, I wil check it again and let you know.

Comment: Yes, but in didSelectRowAt method you explicitly adding the 'ChecklistDetail' name of the storyboard, I know this is possible, I want to  access this view controller from the main.storyboard with didSelectRow method, which you have mentioned.

And I know  if I make a reference of the view controller from the main.storyboard it will work, how to do without that reference.

Comment: I dont know apple giving that feature or not, do some research, i will try it once i get a time